# SH72867 with I2C

Tags: i2c

I am using ‘SH72867(Renesas)’ connect with ‘EEPROM(24LC04B)’ . In the customer’s document at ‘address 0xF0 of EEPROM  have data 0x5555’, But when I reading from this address always return ‘0xFFFF’ and same with other address.
I can’t  write to EEPROM too.
I used I2C sample of Renesas but not run.
Do you have any suggestion about setting up I2C?

Sorry for my bad English and no clear explanation.

Any help apprciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Verify the common issues:

1. Data and clock are connected properly.
2. Pull up resistor on clock and data connected to VCC.
3. Loop the I2C read request, connect scope and verify that I2C signals are OK. In addition check the ACK bit.
4. Verify clock is lower then 400kHz.
5. When using code examples, they usually fit to specific board. Verify that the code example configuration is the same as your board.
6. Some MCU may have more then one I2C pinout options. The code example might use I2C module that connected to diffrent pins.